# Problem in installing testCases_v2 in VScode

Tags: python, installation, pip

Python version = `3.10.1`, pip version = `22.2.2` and I'm using VScode version `1.71.2`. When I try to install `pip install testCases_v2`, I get this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement testCases_v4 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for testCases_v4
```

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: There is no such package: https://pypi.org/project/testCases_v2/ What are trying to install? From what index?

Comment: I'm going through an assignment on jupyter notebook hosted by coursera. There they used this package as ```from testCases_v2 import *```. So. I thought of replicating it in my local system.  But I don't have this module in my system.  Pardon my ignorance, I don't have much experience but how is coursera using that package if there's no such package?  @phd

Comment: I don't know your courses, no advice on that. Most probably there are additional materials accompanying the course.

Comment: Just in case, if anyone is interested in specifics, it's Coursera course "Neural Networks and Deep Learning", Andrew Ng, week 3, programming assignment: "Planar data classification with one hidden layer"